# Use Excel when a macro is running

Tags: excel, vba

I am not sure if this can be done, but it would be great if the user can use the excel spreadsheet while the macro is running at the backend. Is there any way this can be done? Thanks.

EDIT: The user is repeatedly (>10^5 times) generating Random permutations on n items (n ~ 100) through a macro. This might take around 10-15 mins (or more) to get done. So, if the user can open the excel workbook to do other tasks, while the macro is running , it would be nice. (It would typically be a different workbook from the one in which macro is running). Please let me know if this can be done and if yes, any performance effects that it might have on the macro which is running. Thanks.

Comment: adding 
    "doevents" into loops may help a little.

Comment: It actually depends on what the macro is doing. Can you give us more details?

Comment: Also, just for clarity sake, does the user want to use the `SAME` Workbook that the macro is working on, or a different one? Because if it's a different one, you can open a different instance of Excel and work away! Beware that, depending on what your macro does, processing time may be slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user can open a second instance of the Excel application while the macro is running and work as normal on other workbooks. The same workbook can also be opened but as read only.

Comment: I tried this, and it merely goes back to the spreadsheet that is already running.   If the macro execution is stopped, the new workbook opens, but I am prevented from working with it when the macro on the first workbook is restarted.  This may be a feature Microsoft created in order to market a more expensive future version of Excel.  My solution: use a second computer whose working files are synced by means of a flash drive and Microsoft SyncToy.