# VBA Data Download From Web w/out Affecting Other Tasks?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer-11

Is it possible with VBA Excel to download data from a website without affecting other tasks? What I want to achieve is to be able to press a button and keep working on other tasks. Right now, when I run the code below, I can't perform other tasks or the code will break. Thanks for everyone's help/input!

```
Public Sub Get_File()

    Dim sFiletype As String     'Fund type reference
    Dim sFilename As String     'File name (fund type + date of download), if "" then default
    Dim sFolder As String       'Folder name (fund type), if "" then default
    Dim bReplace As Boolean     'To replace the existing file or not
    Dim sURL As String          'The URL to the location to extract information
    Dim pURL As String
    Dim Cell, Rng As Range
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet

    Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
    Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer

    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

    StartTime = Timer

    'Initialize variables
    Set Rng = Range("I2:I15")
    Set Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Macro_Button")

    For Each Cell In Rng
        If Cell <> "" Then
        sFiletype = Cell.Value
        sFilename = sFiletype & "_" & Format(Date, "mmddyyyy")
        sFolder = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cell.Value, Sheet.Range("I2:Z15"), 2, False)
        bReplace = True
        sURL = "www.preqin.com"
        pURL = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cell.Value, Sheet.Range("I2:Z15"), 16, False)

        'Download using the desired approach, XMLHTTP / IE
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cell.Value, Sheet.Range("I2:Z15"), 15, False) = 1 Then
            Call Download_Use_IE(oBrowser, sURL, pURL, sFilename, sFolder, bReplace)
            Else
            Call Download_NoLogin_Use_IE(oBrowser, pURL, sFilename, sFolder, bReplace)
            End If

        Else: GoTo Exit_Sub
        End If
    Next

Exit_Sub:

    'Close IE
    oBrowser.Quit

    'Determine how many seconds code took to run
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
    MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub

Private Sub Download_Use_IE(oBrowser As InternetExplorer, _
                            ByRef sURL As String, _
                            ByRef pURL As String, _
                            Optional ByRef sFilename As String = "", _
                            Optional ByRef sFolder As String = "", _
                            Optional ByRef bReplace As Boolean = True)

    Dim hDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim objInputs As Object
    Dim ele As Object

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    oBrowser.Visible = True

    'Navigate to URL
    Call oBrowser.navigate(sURL)
    While oBrowser.Busy Or oBrowser.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    'Skips log in step if already signed into website
    On Error GoTo LoggedIn

    'Enter username
    oBrowser.document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_cphSiteHeader_ucLoginForm_user_email").Value = "XXX"
    oBrowser.document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_cphSiteHeader_ucLoginForm_user_password").Value = "XXX"

    'Submit the sign in
    oBrowser.document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_cphSiteHeader_ucLoginForm_btnLogin").Click
    'Wait for website to load
    While oBrowser.Busy Or oBrowser.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

LoggedIn:

'Initial data export
    oBrowser.navigate (pURL)
    'Wait for website to load
    While oBrowser.Busy Or oBrowser.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    'Set the htmldocument
    Set hDoc = oBrowser.document

    'Loop and click the download file button
    Set objInputs = oBrowser.document.getElementsbyTagName("input")
    For Each ele In objInputs
        If ele.Title Like "Download Data to Excel" Then
            ele.Click
        End If
    Next

    'Wait for dialogue box to load
    While oBrowser.Busy Or oBrowser.readyState > 3: DoEvents: Wend
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    'IE 9+ requires to confirm save
    Call Download(oBrowser, sFilename, sFolder, bReplace)

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    'Resume
    Debug.Print "Sub Download_Use_IE() " & Err & ": " & Error(Err)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the

```
DoEvents
```

As far i know, is not easy to work with background process and excel.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot work on the Workbook that is running the macro. You can open another instance of Excel, or a read only copy of the workbook running the macro if you would like to work within Excel while the macro is running. [This question has been asked and answered before on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143013/use-excel-when-a-macro-is-running)

It is difficult to determine from your question whether you are talking about "other tasks" as in within Excel or just on your computer in general. My above paragraph answers whether you can  do tasks within Excel while the macro is running.

Comment: Computer in general. What happens is that if I click somewhere else on the screen to read a article, etc., then the macro stops / returns an error.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if this will help, but have you tried turning `screenupdating` off at the beginning and back on at the end?

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately - i provided additional code above in case that might help...

Comment: When you say "read an article, etc.", are you referring to doing another activity in your browser or is it any click on the screen for any program?

Comment: Any program - it can be just scrolling an another Excel workbook, navigating another website, putting a PPT deck together, etc. Wondering if the macro (which retrieves data from the web and saves it down into a specific folder) can just run in the background without being interrupted.

Comment: This issue is unfortunately outside of my area of expertise (sorry I can't be of more help), the only thing I can think of is changing the priority of Excel in Task Manager. If you downgrade the priority Excel has, maybe it'll allow the program to run in the background without closing it out completely?